# The MDRectangleFlatButton(s) don't take the size they are supposed to have in either GridLayout or MDGridLayout. Kivy's Button(s) work fine

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm sure the code and the picture are pretty self-explanatory.
The MDRectangleFlatButton(s) take the whole GridLayout perfectly if I add **'size_hint: 1, 1'** to every single one of them. But then it would change to a different problem **'[CRITICAL] [Clock ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute'** and the app becomes really laggy, so I thought that couldn't be the right way to do it. I just got with Kivy recently so maybe I haven't really understand how sizing works or how KivyMD is different from Kivy in sizing. Any answers, documentations will be highly appreciate. Thanks!

**main.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class CalculatorApp(MDApp):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CalculatorApp().run()
```

**calculator.kv**

```
MainWidget:

#: import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<MainWidget>:

    MDBoxLayout: 
        id: main_box_layout 

        size: root.width, root.height 
        orientation: 'vertical'

#        TextInput:
#            id: calc_screen
#            
#            halign: 'left'
#            text: 'Screen'
        
        GridLayout: 
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#3399FF4C')

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            id: calc_buttons

            cols: 5
            rows: 4

            # 1
            Button:
                text: '%'
            # 2
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 3
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 4
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 5
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 6
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 7
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 8
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 9
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 10
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 11
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 12
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 13
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 14
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 15
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 16
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 17
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 18
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 19
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 20
            Button:
                text: '%'

        MDGridLayout: 
            id: calc_buttons

            cols: 5
            rows: 4

            # 1
            Button:
                text: '%'
            # 2
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 3
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 4
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 5
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 6
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 7
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 8
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 9
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 10
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 11
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 12
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 13
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 14
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 15
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 16
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 17
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 18
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 19
            Button:
                text: '%'

            # 20
            Button:
                text: '%'

        GridLayout: 
            canvas.after:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#FF66994C')

                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            id: calc_buttons

            cols: 5
            rows: 4

            # 1
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'
            # 2
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 3
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 4
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 5
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 6
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 7
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 8
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 9
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 10
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 11
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 12
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 13
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 14
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 15
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 16
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 17
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 18
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 19
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 20
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

        MDGridLayout: 
            md_bg_color: hex('66FF994C')
            id: calc_buttons

            cols: 5
            rows: 4

            # 1
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'
            # 2
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 3
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 4
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 5
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 6
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 7
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 8
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 9
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 10
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 11
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 12
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 13
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 14
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 15
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 16
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 17
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 18
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 19
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'

            # 20
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '%'
```

**Picture of the app running**
[image: Picture of the app running]

**Edit**
I tried to calculate the size of each button once in the GridLayout before the buttons. The buttons' initial size is still their default size. It works when I resize the App's window. So how can I make their initial size the one I calculated?

**calculator.kv**

```
MainWidget:

#: import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

<MainWidget>:

    MDBoxLayout: 
        id: main_box_layout 

        size: root.width, root.height 
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: calc_screen
            
            font_size: dp(25)
            size_hint: 1, .2
            halign: 'left'
            text: '0'
        
        MDGridLayout: 
            id: calc_buttons

            orientation: 'lr-bt'
            cols: 5
            rows: 4

            button_width: self.width / 5
            button_height: self.height / 4

            # 1
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '0'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height

                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 2
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '.'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 3
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '('
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 4
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: ')'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 4.5 cuz i forgot it
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '='
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_equal()

            # 5
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '1'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 6
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '2'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 7
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '3'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 8
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '+'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 9
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '-'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 10
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '4'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 11
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '5'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 12
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '6'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 13
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: 'x'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, '*')

            # 14
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: ':'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, '/')

            # 15
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '7'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 16
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '8'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 17
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: '9'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_number_operator_button(self, self.text)

            # 18
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: 'DEL'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_delete()

            # 19
            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                text: 'AC'
                font_size: dp(20)
                size: self.parent.button_width, self.parent.button_height
                on_release: root.on_release_all_clear()
```

**Before resizing the Window**
[image: Before resizing the Window]

**After resizing the Window**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is a "feature" of the KivyMD `Buttons`. Many of those `Buttons` have their `size_hint` set to `(None, None)` and their size is set by KivyMd.

From the [documentation](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/button/index.html#mdflatbutton):

> You cannot use the size_hint_x parameter for KivyMD buttons (the width
> of the buttons is set automatically)!
>
> However, if there is a need to increase the width of the button, you
> can use the parameter increment_width:

```
MDFlatButton:
    text: "MDFLATBUTTON"
    increment_width: "164dp"
```

Comment: Thanks. So I shouldn't try to make KivyMD's buttons size-adaptive?

Comment: Of course you can make them size-adaptive. Just letting you know why you have to use `size_hint: 1,1`. Not sure why you are getting the `Clock` warning, or why your app is laggy, since I don't see that behavior.