# How can I modify MDButtons' size without using font_size in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm using KivyMD and trying to resize my MDButtons but it seems like their size only changes based on their font_size which seems to be the KivyMD default setting.

I have tried this [docs](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.1/components/button/index.html#mdflatbutton) (using increment_width:), this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68609684/the-mdrectangleflatbuttons-dont-take-the-size-they-are-supposed-to-have-in-ei) even try to set its size_hint and size but it seems hopeless.

So I wonder if is there any way to set the button size individually (not font_size) just like Button in Kivy?

Here is the example, I still don't know how do I get it wrong:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = """
MDScreen:
    MDFlatButton:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
                
        text: 'MDButton'
        increment_width: "164dp" # replacing this with size_hint:None,None then size: doesn't work at all
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}


"""


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Example().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `padding` to increase the size of the `MDFlatButton`:

```
MDScreen:
    MDFlatButton:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,0,0,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        padding: 200, 100  # increase the size of the MDFlatButton
        text: 'MDButton'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work because it's pretty weird but I noticed that KivyMD DOES respect explicit `width` values if I express them like

```
width:  self.parent.width * 0 + dp(140.0)  # or 140
```

Naturally `self.parent.width` isn't adding anything but magically if I do that, the `MDRectangleFlatIconButton` is 140 wide regardless of the text I put inside (which I change dinamically). Weird.